# autocad in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a software in vb.net that can read autocad files and get the dimensions out of it. How can i do that. If anyone can help me it will be very helpful and will really appreciate them. 
Thank you

Comment: Hi, are you looking to automate or otherwise communicate with an instance of AutoCAD or are you looking for something which is going to work stand-alone (which does not require AutoCAD to be installed on the machine)?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the AutoCAD .Net developer's API Guide:
http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html

Here's a link to their developer center:
http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=1911627&siteID=123112

Here's a couple of forums for developer's using the .Net API's:
http://forums.augi.com/forumdisplay.php?f=215

http://discussion.autodesk.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=152

Here's a blog entry from someone suggesting how to get started (second to last paragraph):
http://cadingandcoding.blogspot.com/2007/07/autocadnet-programming-vbnet-or-c.html

Here's a video from AutoCAD University on the API:
http://au.autodesk.com/?nd=class&session_id=66

Here's another blog entry with hints on how to get started:
http://autodesk.blogs.com/between_the_lines/2009/07/autocad-net-developers-guide-posted-online.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. Klabranche. But i dint get the codes for the same. I am searching for a sample codes for the same. If you can help me it will be very helpful and i will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can fine the getting started tutorials and respective code for AutoCAD.Net at following link:

[AutoCAD.Net Tutorials & Sample Code](http://www.caddsoftsolutions.com/Tutorials.htm)